# How to create a count down circular chart using android scichart

Tags: java, android, scichart

I am trying to use Scichart to create a countdown circular chart using scichart. Wondering, if anyone can point me to an example.

Answer (score 2):

To Create a countdown Circular chart using scichart use `SciPieChartSurface`

Use this code:

```
final SciChartBuilder sciChartBuilder = SciChartBuilder.instance();
SciPieChartSurface progressChart = findViewById(R.id.progressChart);

.........

final float donutSeriesHeight = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12, progressChart.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

IPieRenderableSeries donutSeries = sciChartBuilder.newDonutSeries().withSegments(
        sciChartBuilder.newPieSegment()
                .withValue(eldChart.getPercentage())
                .withFillColor(finishedColor)
                .withStrokeStyle(finishedColor)
                .build(),

        sciChartBuilder.newPieSegment()
                .withValue(100 - eldChart.getPercentage())
                .withFillColor(unfinishedColor)
                .withStrokeStyle(unfinishedColor)
                .build()
)
        .withHeightSizingModeP(SizingMode.Absolute)
        .withHeight(donutSeriesHeight)
        .build();

donutSeries.setSegmentSpacing(0);
donutSeries.setStartAngle(90);

Collections.addAll(progressChart.getRenderableSeries(), donutSeries);
```

And to update the progress only update the donutSeries Segments value

For update:

```
if ( progressChart.getRenderableSeries().size() > 0 ){
    PieSegmentCollection segmentsCollection = progressChart.getRenderableSeries().get(0).getSegmentsCollection();

    if (segmentsCollection.size() == 2) {
        IPieSegment iPieSegment1 = segmentsCollection.get(0);
        iPieSegment1.setValue(eldChart.getPercentage());

        IPieSegment iPieSegment2 = segmentsCollection.get(1);
        iPieSegment2.setValue(100-eldChart.getPercentage());
    }
}
```

Here `getRenderableSeries().get(0).getSegmentsCollection()` will return a `ObservableCollection<IPieSegment>` so just updating `IPieSegment` value will reflect on UI.

Hope this will help you